# fatal error: module 'FirebaseAnalytics' not found - Ionic Native Cordova build

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic2, firebase-analytics

When doing a 'ionic cordova build ios' on my app, I'm getting a fatal error saying the "module 'FirebaseAnalytics' not found" in my FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.m file

How do I correct this?

I've followed the instructions for installation on http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-analytics/

Here's my Ionic info if needed:
global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.5.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1 
Ionic CLI        : 3.5.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.1
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.2
Cordova Platforms               : ios 4.1.1
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.4.2
```

System:

```
Node       : v8.1.3
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b 
ios-deploy : 1.9.1 
ios-sim    : 5.0.13 
npm        : 5.3.0
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Is your app have phonegap-plugin-push plugin installed?

Comment: No it does not have the phonegap-plugin-push plugin installed.  I'm using Ionic 2 and this is the only plugin that I needed to install outside of the usual that Ionic 2 installs automatically.  Would it help if I installed it?  I thought I saw someone else say the had a conflict with it.

Thanks for any help you can give.